# How to retrieve Oracle Clob more than 4000 characters ODP.NET

Tags: c#-4.0, odp.net

I am trying to retrieve CLOB data via ODP.NET. 
My problem is that reader.GetValue(i).ToString() can return only up to 4000 characters and the rest of the data is truncated. 
If I use reader.GetOracleClob(1).Value I got "Specified cast is not valid" error.

Any idea what I have missed? I am using ODP.NET 4.0

Below is my code.

```
using (OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection())
{
  oConn.ConnectionString = pConnstr;
  oConn.Open();
  using (OracleCommand oCmd = new OracleCommand("select varchar_column, clob_column from test", oConn))
  {
    oCmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;
    string key, value, value1;
    var rd = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read())
    {
      if (rd.IsDBNull(1)) { value = ""; }
      else
      {
        key = rd.GetValue(0).ToString();
        value = rd.GetValue(1).ToString(); // unable to get more than 4000.
        value1 = rd.GetOracleClob(1).Value; // Specified cast is not valid.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I found in Oracle Doc that When the InitialLOBFetchSize property is set to a nonzero value, the GetOracleBlob, GetOracleClob, GetOracleBlobForUpdate, and GetOracleClobForUpdate typed accessor methods are disabled. That may help explain why I got "Specified cast is not valid" error.

However, I still cannot get data beyond 4000 limit.

I have tried different combinations documented here
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featData.htm#autoId6
But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the code works correctly and gets the data it supposed to get. I just didn't realize that my data is incomplete and appeared to be a retrieval problem at the first look. Sorry.

The following is the good code.

```
using (OracleConnection oConn = new OracleConnection())
{
  oConn.ConnectionString = pConnstr;
  oConn.Open();
  using (OracleCommand oCmd = new OracleCommand("select varchar_column, clob_column from test", oConn))
  {
    oCmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;
    string key, value;
    var rd = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (rd.Read())
    {
      if (rd.IsDBNull(1)) { value = ""; }
      else
      {
        key = rd.GetValue(0).ToString();
        value = rd.GetValue(1).ToString(); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution did not work for me.  It turns out my data was not CLOB or BLOB but LONG Data!  So the fix is just to set:

```
oCmd.InitialLONGFetchSize= -1;
```

Instead of

```
oCmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = -1;
```

Please leave a comment if this method worked for you also.